# Context menu in number fields in Firefox 33.0

Tags: firefox, contextmenu

In Firefox 33.0, when right clicking in a number field, the context menu doesn't have the usual copy/paste options.

Is there any way to make Firefox display the "old" (left one below) context menu when right clicking number fields?

[image: Context menu in a normal text field] [image: Context menu in a number field]

Try it out here:
http://jsbin.com/qapavuleli/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a possible bug in Firefox:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1059219